# Eclipse Egit Failed to commit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

I got Eclipse for PHP developers 3.0.2 With Egit 2.2.0 installed, and I am on windows 7
I got my project and repository set up and linked.
Yet i cant commit changes. this is the error i get:

```
Exception caught during execution of add command
   Exception caught during execution of add command
```

I got Git for windows installed and set that in the Git configuration.
I also got my HOME variable set up with %USERPROFILE%

Also my project location is on a remote server that i mapped to Z:

This includes the git repo as well.

That remote location has Lubuntu 12.10 installed.
It has git installed as well.

Comment: I would advise against having the Git repository you are working with on a network share, it can cause various problems.

Comment: but i dont know how to make the git repo and the working location in diferent locations...can you tell me how?

Comment: I assume you push against a central repository that is different from the one on the network share, no? I meant that your local repository and working directory should be on a local disk. Separate locations for the `.git` and its associated working directory is not supported by Git, they are always a unit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found what was the problem. 
Git locked it self witha file in the ./git/index.lock

After i removed that everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @NaGeL182.. I got it working now because Git locked

So I need to delete the   **.git/index.lock** file

1. On Mac just Hit below command On Terminal

> rm -f ./.git/index.lock

on Windows

> del .git\index.lock

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents...
My git workspace is mapped locally on the dropbox folder (i'm a bit paranoid and prefers double backup options). Sometimes there's a mismatch with the sync process and dropbox keeps the git .lock file.
Since all i care about is my resources and not the git metadata - i've simply unchecked the .git folder from synching online.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try, go to your repository and execute below command !

```
chmod -R 777 .git
```

Comment: Before you paste this in even more locations, please take the time to read [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue on a Windows 11 machine. The fix was to remove the 'hidden' attribute from all files under the .git directory